# How do I use the Wolfram Language Evaluator in Chat-Enabled Notebook in v13.3?

Tags: chatai, version-13.3

In the [release blog for v13.3](https://writings.stephenwolfram.com/2023/06/llm-tech-and-a-lot-more-version-13-3-of-wolfram-language-and-mathematica/) it appears you are able to directly evaluate the code from the LLM chat output using the **Wolfram Language Evaluator?**

[image]

However when I try the same, that option is not there; the only way to evaluate the code is to send it to hover over the code and send it to evaluate in a new cell below.

[image]

How do I enable the Wolfram Language Evaluator?